# Calculus Volume Cylindrical Shell Method

Tags: calculus, volume

Please use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume generated by rotating the region bounded by

- $\displaystyle y=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin x}x&\text{ if }x>0\\1&\text{ if }x=0\end{cases}$
- $y=0$
- $x=0$
- $x=\pi$

about the $y$-axis.

I tried to do it using

\begin{align}
V&=\int_0^\pi2\pi x\frac{\sin x}x\,\mathrm dx\\
 &=2\pi\int_0^\pi\sin x\,\mathrm dx\\
 &=4\pi.
\end{align}

Is this correct? What about when $x=0$? Doesn't it should affect the integrand? so maybe something like
\begin{align}
V&=\int_{0^-}^{0^+} 2\pi x\mathrm dx\\
\end{align}
What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes your answer is correct using cylindrical shell method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct; the answer is $4\pi$ for the reasn that you gave. And, if $f$ is your function, then$$0\times f(0)=0\times1=0=\sin(0).$$ So, there is no problem with $x=0$.